# exec-maven-plugin: Can I run exec:exec goal without first running the toolchains:toolchain goal?

Tags: java, maven, maven-exec-plugin, maven-toolchains-plugin

I've inherited an application that only compiles and runs in Java 1.8. Because I don't want to make Java 1.8 the primary jvm on my machine, I felt that the best way to manage this was through Maven toolchains. Configuring the maven-compiler-plugin was pretty straight forward, but I also want to add the ability to execute the service via Maven in order to take advantage of the toolchain I have configured for 1.8.

The challenge is that I don't seem to be able to get the exec-maven-plugin to use the toolchain as documented. According to the documentation, I would think that the exec-maven-plugin would utilize the maven-toolchains-plugin as needed. However, in order to get `exec:exec` to use the right toolchain, I have to use:

`mvn toolchains:toolchain exec:exec`

This works, but the [documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-toolchains.html#The_.22jdk.22_Toolchain) leads me to think that the toolchain would be configured automatically without me needing to execute the `toolchains:toolchain` goal.

pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>toolchain</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <toolchains>
          <jdk>
            <version>1.8</version>
          </jdk>
        </toolchains>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
        
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>-classpath</argument>
          <classpath></classpath>
          <argument>com.my.Main</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

toolchains.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<toolchains>
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <id>1.8</id>
      <version>1.8</version>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

Additional Note: I also tried configuring the exec-maven-plugin to run on `exec:java` with the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <mainClass>com.my.Main</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

However this does not work, not even with `mvn toolchains:toolchain exec:java`.

Is there a way to configure this so that I only have to run `mvn exec:exec`, or `mvn exec:java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is you must ensure that the `toolchains` plugin itself is part of your build.  Or that's what [the relevant documentation seems to say](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html#using-toolchains-in-your-project).  (I see above you have that; what I'm saying is yes, that is required.)

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but it does seem to be the correct answer. :)